# How Can i Remove the background image of my ucoz website?

Tags: css, image, web, background

Well I have a ucoz website with the theme eminent and i was wondering how to remove the background image

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?dckk1q60xkd42vx) is the theme css code:

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the CSS here

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
#page {background:#0d0d0d url('/images/body.png') repeat-x;margin:0;padding:10px 0 0 0;}
```

to:

```
#page {background:#0d0d0d repeat-x;margin:0;padding:10px 0 0 0;}
```